# How can I install PHPmyadmin on Mac Lion using Homebrew

Tags: phpmyadmin, homebrew

How can I install PHPmyadmin using homebrew, if that possible. I'm using Mac 10.7.

I installed Homebrew, and it's working perfectly. I use it to download php 5.4 and mysql. Both are working perfectly, and also the homebrew, and it's updated.

Comment: How about using XAMPP or MAMP ? Much easier to maintain & use (though the versions may not be up-to-date)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the command if you have homebrew installed:

```
brew install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: doesnt work anymore

Comment: doesnt work anymore

Comment: Would be nice if you would add some guide on how to use/access it after the installation.

Answer (score 35):

You may need to set up some dependencies first. Here's what I had to do:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install phpmyadmin
```

This information was from the homepage for [Homebrew-PHP](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php), "a centralized repository for PHP-related brews".

Comment: there is no github repo josegonzales/homebrew-php anymore so please use "brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php", it worked for me

Comment: @nerdess Thanks for that -- I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

as of this writing, `brew install homebrew/php/phpmyadmin` works

Comment: and then....? do what?

Answer (score 0):

This page gives great instructions: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-amp-osx-10-9-mavericks-homebrew/

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

Follow These Steps:-

1. Install Phpmyadmin:

> brew install phpmyadmin

2. Now, enter below command and follow the instructions as mentioned:

> brew info phpmyadmin

3. Apache Restart

> Apache Restart

4. Open Phpmyadmin:

> http://localhost/phpmyadmin

5. If you are unable to login with phpmyadmin :

   Change in phpmyadmin config file [/usr/local/etc/phpmyadmin.config.inc.php]

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Now You Are Good To Go!!!

Answer (score 0):

Install autoconf, which is needed for the installation of phpMyAdmin:

```
brew install autoconf
```

And set the $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable:

If you use the default Bash shell:

```
echo 'PHP_AUTOCONF="'$(which autoconf)'"' >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile
```

or if you use ZSH:

```
echo 'PHP_AUTOCONF="'$(which autoconf)'"' >> ~/.zshrc && . ~/.zshrc
```

Since now you're all set, you can finish this part with the actual installation of phpMyAdmin:

```
brew install phpmyadmin
```